# Award Drupal User points after contribution

Tags: contributions, drupal-rules

I would like to create a Drupal Rule to award Drupal userpoints upon a civicrm contribution being added to a member record through membership sign up.

Ideally the points awarded are dependent on which price field (price set) is selected, ie bronze member = 10 userpoints, silver member = 20 userpoints etc

I have been playing around with rules but can't seem get this one...any pointers would be most appreciated.

(pasted from answer/comment)

I thought it would be a simple rule. When a contribution is saved, of a specific type userpoints are added to the record. But no...

So far...I created a price set with the required price options for both membership and contribution.

Then went to Drupal Rules and made various attempts at setting up a rule to award userpoints on either signing up to a membership or making a payment. A combination of the following;

In terms of the event I have tried; after saving a new civicrm contribution, after saving a civicrm price field, price field value etc

Condition: I have tried Data comparison, entity is of type, list contains item etc based on price field id, price field value id

Action; Award user points.

Non of the above (or combinations) have given me a result when adding a contribution or membership to the user record.

So I'm pretty much lost. Help...!!!

Comment: maybe you could clarify what you have tried so folk understand what sort of effort / attempts you have made

Answer (score 1):

To make this work I’m pretty sure you’ll need CiviCRM Entity module. We’ve used that to create Drupal accounts after/when a Contact purchases a Membership.